# Upload de imagem usando CGI Python - Não funciona!

Tags: python, python-3.x, script

Olá, criei um arquivo html com um  e pretendo selecionar uma imagem de um diretório e após clicar em submit essa imagem deverá ser salva em outro diretório. Alguma ajuda?

Isso é o que tentei até agora...

index.html

```
<form name="pyform" method="POST" action="upload.py"> 
   <input type="file" name="image" /><br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

upload.py

```
#!c:/Python34/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

import cgi,cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
file = form['image'].value

upload_dir = 'C:/wamp/www/upload/' # esse é o diretório onde vou salvar a imagem

f = open(upload_dir + file, 'w')
f.write(file)
f.close()
```

Observei que após executar o código, um arquivo com o mesmo nome da imagem é criado, porém, com tamanho 0kb e não pode ser exibida.

Comment: you managed to miss two different simple steps, and have each of these steps directed in one of the two answers bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve abrir, ler e gravar o arquivo em modo binário desse jeito:

```
f = open(file, mode = 'rb') #'rb' para ler arquivos binários 
f2 = open(upload_dir + file, 'wb')  #'wb' para gravar arquivos binários
f2.write(f.read())
```

Ou você pode fazer assim:

```
with open(file, mode='rb') as f:
    with open(upload_dir+file, mode='wb') as f2:
        f2.write(f.read())
```

desse modo os recursos são fechados automaticamente.

Comment: Na verdade, são dois problemas - um é o acesso aos dados do arquivo - o outro é no form HTML, cuja tag `<form> `  deve cotner o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data" ` como na resposta do @Wallace

Comment: O uso do  `with ` assim é um pouco overkill também - mas se for feito, desde há bastante tempo é possível ter mais de um objeto com gerenciamento de contextos no mesmo comando with, separados por vírgula - não há a menor necessidade de se aninhar dois  `with`

Answer (score 1):

Bem,acho que seu problema é mais simples de resolver.

Seu formulário deve conter o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Acho que você se esqueceu.

Comment: na verdade, faltam duas coisas - uma é isso, a outra é que o campo de envio do arquivo  não tem m atributo "value" - mas um atributo "file" que deve ser lido como na resposta do @ironman